# R Markdown, ensure that code output is not broken up between multiple pages

Tags: r, r-markdown

How can I ensure that the dataset in my RMarkdown document prints on a single page rather than being split between pages.

I want to make it so that if the the output is going to be printed at the end of a page (and will therefore run over to the next page) it will instead be printed on the next page.

[image: Example_Picture]